# TV Episode involving a male and a female reporter where she gets the exciting pieces including one involving a werewolf

Tags: story-identification, tv, werewolf

I think I saw this on PBS somewhere in the late 1980s to the early 1990s. It might have been a segment on a show like *3-2-1 Contact* or *Electric Company*. The core scene sticking in my head involves a pair of reporters, one male and one female. The man thinks that the woman gets all of the exciting reporting jobs. While reporting on a segment along the lines of "how to share your toys", a set of parents seem oddly frightened as he goes upstairs to talk to the children, with their daughter complaining that her brother doesn't play nicely with her toys and sometimes breaks them. As he's interviewing her about that, said brother shows up... and he's a werewolf, who indeed is very rough on his sister's toys. The reporter is thrilled that he's on an exciting case only to have the female reporter show up (I think maybe crashing through a wall to do so?), revealing that she was assigned to a story about the werewolf problem in the city. I think it ends with her trying to wrestle the werewolf down while he looks at the camera with bemused resignation.

Hmm... and as I cast my mind back, now I feel like he, during the segment, made a comment that "she's probably covering a segment about how to play nice with your toys" and it's revealed that she stumbled onto the werewolf segment as a result of it, which would imply that he had gotten the more exciting segment to start with.

I have vague associations of non-fantasy segments which may have been from the same episode:

- One in which a group of kids play pranks on a home-owner, and the consequences of them getting caught. One involved dumping a bag of flour down his chimney. Looking back on it with what I know now, I'm not certain whether the intent was that the the flour snuffed the fire, just made a mess, or made a bit more of a bang in the same manner as a grain silo explosion. My memory of the scene had one of them hopping down from the roof of the house to the roof or a garage/carport, and then maybe to the roof of a car, only to be grabbed by the irate homeowner.
- One in which a group of kid protagonists are outside of a supermarket, attempting to either solicit for signatures or sell something for charity, but with little success. I honestly don't remember whether the segment was about math (with them breaking down how many signatures they could get assuming the current trend continued) or a more moral lesson about how sometimes such work is hard but it's worth it in the end.

Comment: That doesn't sound like *3-2-1 Contact* (which didn't do fiction, apart from The Bloodhound Gang) or *The Electric Company*, which was solely about reading.  However, there were other public TV shows....

Comment: Square One Television was a kids sketch anthology show produced by Children’s Television Workshop, aired on PBS, and was focused on math which ran for 230 episodes, and sometimes included fantastical or zany elements in the sketches. Sketches included live action comedy segments as well as game shows, and even cartoons. It ran from 1987-1992 and so both its format and air date at least include it as possibility.

Comment: That is possible. I do remember watching Square One, although I feel like this was earlier.